# How to add units to a number using Unitful in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm loading a JSON file in Julia. The file contains two fields `length` and `length_units`. How can I construct a variable in Julia using the Unitful library using the two fields from the JSON file.

Let's say I've got the data in a dict as follows:

```
d = Dict("length"=>5, "length_units"=>"m")
```

The documentation only shows how to construct quantities as follows:

```
L = 5u"m"
```

but this is manual. I would like to use the data stored in the dict to do something like this:

```
L = Quantity(d["length"], d["length_units"])
```

but the above does not work. How can I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parsing the unit with `Unitful.uparse` and then concatenating the two.

```
using Unitful

L = d["length"] * uparse(d["length_units"])
5 m

typeof(L)
Quantity{Int64, , Unitful.FreeUnits{(m,), , nothing}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is [`uparse`](https://github.com/PainterQubits/Unitful.jl/blob/a09bdaac255d456e6315b77979a48956aca1d3a3/src/user.jl#L643):

```
using Unitful

@assert Quantity(5, uparse("m")) == 500u"cm"  # true
```

It is not documented in the README as of the writing of this answer, but is exported by the package and mentioned in [the release notes for version 1.0.0](https://github.com/PainterQubits/Unitful.jl/blob/a09bdaac255d456e6315b77979a48956aca1d3a3/NEWS.md#v100-2020-01-27):

> The uparse function can be used to parse units and quantities from a string

Answer (score 0):

for a verrrry wrong way to get there ...

```
Unitful.Quantity(d["length"], eval(Symbol(d["length_units"])) )
5 m
```

But I have been away from Julia for years (0.7) and never heard of Unitful before just now.

https://github.com/PainterQubits/Unitful.jl/blob/master/test/runtests.jl is as close to doc as I found

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid unexpected inputs which can throw the program off, it is best to pre-prepare a dictionary of possible units. It is reasonable to assume the units in `d["length_units"]` are from a limited set (that doesn't include *Planck length* for example). To use this in code:

```
using Unitful

str2u = Dict(
  "m" => u"m",
  "cm" => u"cm"
)

# and then use it:
d["length"] * str2u[d["length_units"]]
```

A method to more easily generate `str2u` would be:

```
gen_str2u(names) =
   Dict(s => Unitful.lookup_units(Unitful, Symbol(s)) for s in names)

names = ["m", "cm", "ft"]
str2u = gen_str2u(names)
```